# Using sparksql inside pyspark map logic not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a number of small files. I want to load them in an RDD. And then map over them to execute an algorithm on these files in parallel. The algorithm will require fetching data from HDFS/Hive-tables. When I use SparkSQL to fetch the data, I get the below error:

> pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It
>   appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a
>   broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only
>   be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more
>   information, see SPARK-5063.

SparkSQL uses SQLContext which is a wrapper on SparkContext. Does this mean I cannot use SparkSQL inside a code that executes on workers? But then,  it would be too limiting.

Can someone please share some knowledge on how to code my logic in PySpark?

Here is a sample PySpark code that I am using:

```
def apply_algorithm(filename):
    /* SparkSQL logic goes here */ 
    /* some more logic */
    return someResult


def main(argv):
    print "Entered main method"
    input_dir = sys.argv[1]
    output_dir = sys.argv[2]

    fileNameContentMapRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(input_dir)
    print "fileNameContentMapRDD = " , fileNameContentMapRDD.collect()

    resultRDD = fileNameContentMapRDD.map(lambda x : apply_algorithm(x[0]))

    print resultRDD.collect()
    print "end of main."
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean I cannot use SparkSQL inside a code that executes on workers?

Yes, it means exactly this. You can use neither `RDDs` nor `DataFrames` from parallelized context.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I would like to process each of the small files in parallel (because they are completely independent). What options are suitable to query HDFS/HiveTables within the worker - when I cannot use SparkSQL?

Comment: There should be no need to query HDFS/Hive tables within the worker. You can just query the relevant data in driver. When you call collect, Spark will distribute the evaluation of the query over the different workers nodes and return the results back to the driver.

Comment: Then I will have to restructure my code somewhat like  this:

Comment: Then I will have to restructure my code somewhat like  this:                def apply_algorithm(filename):
    /* SparkSQL logic goes here */ 
    /* some more logic */
    /* write output to a separate file for each input file*/                                                                    
 def main(argv):
    print "Entered main method"
    input_dir = sys.argv[1]
    output_dir = sys.argv[2]
     /* loop over each file in input files dir and call apply_algorithm(filename) for each file */

Comment: But if I loop over input files as shown above, I am processing them sequentially - seems to defeat the purpose why I looked at Spark for this. Also, after processing each inputfiles independently, I need to produce separate output files. I can only leverage Spark's distributed computing for processing within a file & not across files.